# Ascending and descending order between NOT NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

With this query:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        concat(e.FirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as Employee_Name, 
        g.GrantName, 
        g.Amount, 
        case 
            when g.Amount IS NULL THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END AS IS_NULL_Amount
    from Employee e 
        LEFT OUTER join [Grant] g
            ON g.EmpID = e.EmpID
)

SELECT 
    CTE.Employee_Name, 
    CTE.GrantName, 
    CTE.Amount 
from CTE
ORDER BY CTE.IS_NULL_Amount desc
```

I get these results:

```
Employee_Name      GrantName                   Amount
---------------------------------------------------------
Barry Brown        K-Land fund trust           15750.00
Lee Osako          TALTA_Kishan International  18100.00
David Kennson      BIG 6's Foundation%         21000.00
Eric Bender        Just Mom                    9900.00
David Lonning      92 Purr_Scents %% team      4750.00
David Lonning      Robert@BigStarBank.com      18100.00
David Lonning      www.@-Last-U-Can-Help.com   25000.00
David Lonning      Big Giver Tom               95900.00
James Newton       Mega Mercy                  55000.00
Terry O'Haire      Ben@MoreTechnology.com      41000.00
Sally Smith        Thank you @.com             21500.00
Barbara O'Neil     NULL                        NULL
Phil Wilconkinski  NULL                        NULL
Janis Smith        NULL                        NULL
Alex Adams         NULL                        NULL
John Marshbank     NULL                        NULL
Lisa Kendall       NULL                        NULL

(17 row(s) affected)
```

How can I sort ASC and DESC only between not-NULL values?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "sort ASC and DESC only between Not NULL values". What column do you want to sort on, Amount? And keep nulls last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort over IS_NULL_Amount  and Amount

```
ORDER BY CTE.IS_NULL_Amount desc,Amount asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this order by clause:

```
order by cte.Is_Null_Amount desc, EmployeeName
```

Or

```
order by cte.Is_Null_Amount desc, Amount desc
```